Constant disk writes to home dir by Microsoft Edge
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS after using Linux Mint for some time, but am having issues with Microsoft Edge constantly writing to disk (home partition).
Here is the accumulative output of iotop over a period of about 2 minutes:
 193517 be/4 russ         52.00 K     51.53 M msedge --enable-features=WebRTCPipeWir~ktopPWAsRunOnOsLogin [ThreadPoolForeg]
    868 be/3 root          0.00 B     47.30 M [jbd2/dm-0-8]
 193518 be/4 russ          0.00 B     41.64 M msedge --enable-features=WebRTCPipeWir~ktopPWAsRunOnOsLogin [ThreadPoolForeg]
 193549 be/4 russ          0.00 B     15.98 M msedge --type=utility --utility-sub-ty~iations-seed-version [ThreadPoolForeg]
 193468 be/4 russ          0.00 B      7.98 M msedge --enable-features=WebRTCPipeWir~blyTrapHandler,DesktopPWAsRunOnOsLogin
 193532 be/4 russ          0.00 B      3.17 M msedge --enable-features=WebRTCPipeWir~ktopPWAsRunOnOsLogin [ThreadPoolForeg]

After some googling, I have tried several fixes from similar issues:

Clearing browser data.
Disabling extensions.
Resetting settings.

Unfortunately, none of the above has helped.
Has anyone else had this issue and can offer any advice?
Update: I tried running Chrome instead today and noticed it has the same issue, constant disk writing when just sitting on a new tab page with no other tabs open. Perhaps this is a Chromium issue?

Perhaps this is an issue shared by all chromium based browsers. Try firefox

I have exact problem. Tons of 3second lags on all pages, and Edge writes constatly into disc (SSD, M2).
